# There is no injective morphism from $\mathbb S_7$ to $\mathbb A_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I am trying to show that it doesn't exist an injective group morphism $f:\mathbb S_7 \to \mathbb A_8$. If there is an injective morphism from $\mathbb S_7$to $\mathbb A_8$ then $\mathbb S_7$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb A_8$. With this in mind, if there exists an element $x$ of order $n$ in $\mathbb S_7$, then $f(x)$ has the same order in $\mathbb A_8$. I was trying to arrive at a contradiction but I couldn't find the appropiate element. I would really appreciate some suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably overkill, but here goes: In view of the orders of $S_7$ and $A_8$, it suffices to show that $A_8$ has no subgroup $H$ of index $4$. If there were such an $H$, then $A_8$ would act transitively on the set of four left cosets of $H$, and the kernel of that action would be a normal subgroup of $A_8$ of index at least $4$ and at most $4!=24$. That contradicts the fact that $A_8$ is simple.

Comment: I don't understand two points: 1) why or how would $\mathbb A_8$ act transitively on the four left cosets of $H$? 2) I see that the kernel can't be just the identity element since the order of $\mathbb A_8$ is $\dfrac{8!}{2}$ and the order of the image is less than or equal to $24$, but why the kernel can't be all $\mathbb A_8$? Maybe I am not understanding the underlying action.

Comment: @user156441 The transitive action is as follows. An element $g$ of $A_8$ sends a left coset $qH$ of $H$ to the left coset $(gq)H$. This is transitive because, given any two left cosets, say $qH$ and $rH$, there is some $g$ sending the first to the second, namely $g=rq^{-1}$.  If the kernel of the action were all of $A_8$, that would mean every element of $A_8$ sends every left coset to itself, which is certainly not the case (by transitivity, or because the only way $g$ can fix the coset $H$ is to be a member of $H$).

Comment: So, I guess you've basically proven that if a simple group $G$ has a subgroup $H$, then $|G| \leq [G:H]!$

Comment: @AlexZorn Right (except for $H=G$ of course). I expect this general form of the result is in some standard sources, but I'm away from home and can't easily check.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: So I get why the kernel of the group action is non trivial, which is enough to prove the original claim, but why is there the upper bound of the size of the kernel of 24?

Comment: Here's where I'm confused. You can either have the group action $f:A_8 \times A_8/H \to A_8/H$ or you can have the group homomorphism $f':A_8 \to A_8/H$ with $f(a,gH)=(ag)H$ and $f'(a) = aH$. Wouldn't looking at $\ker f'$ be enough for our purposes? It isn't all of $A_8$ since $a \notin H$ means $f'(a) \neq H$ and it isn't the identity group since $h \in H$ means $f'(h)=H$ and $H$ is not trivial. So this should do just as much, that is getting a normal subgroup of $A_8$, without group actions.

Comment: I realize now that since the kernel of a group action fixes all elements of the set it is acting on, that is, $a \in \ker f$ means $a(gH)=gH$ for all $g \in A_8$, I now don't understand why $|\ker f| \geq 4$. I thought transitivity meant that would work, but it seems to me that's only if you are talking about $\ker f'$.

Comment: @nayrb I think you've misread my answer.  It's not the size but the index of the kernel that has to be between $4$ and $24$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Makes sooo much more sense! Thanks!